# Insert data to a SQL Server database that contains apostrophes

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I'm making this program on Vb.net 2012 that has a connection to SQL Server 2012.

One of the columns of this database table is `Description`, and in some cases the date may include apostrophes, for example... 'chainsaw 15'3" X 1 1/2 X .050 X 3/4'

When I run the query the apostrophe that is between the data causes an error at the syntax of the query, this is the query line in VB.net.

```
CMD.CommandText = 
"INSERT INTO Table_ARTICLES 
 (NUMPART, DESCRIPTION, LOCATION, MAX, ACTUAL, MIN, Unidad_de_medida) 
 VALUES ('" & txtNumParte.Text & "', '" & txtDescripcion.Text & "', 
  '" & txtLocaclizacion.Text & "', '" & txtMaximo.Text & "', '" & txtActual.Text & "',
  '" & txtMin.Text & "', '" & cmbUnidad.Text & "')"
```

Does anybody know how to make this query accept those characters on the query?

Comment: 1) Don't tag SQL Server questions with the MySQL tag. Two entirely different products. 2) Don't build SQL strings via concatenation... you're just asking for SQL injection attacks and issues exactly like this. 3) Use parameterized SQL and the problem goes away.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Use SQL parameters and you'll also avoid data type mismatch errors and many many other problems.  Creating SQL simply isnt meant to be that tedious.  Also please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 3):

As @pmbAustin pointed out, is a **terrible** idea to build sql statements via string concatenation due to SQL Injection attacks and other problems. The approach you should use is called a parametrized query:

```
CMD.CommandText = "INSERT INTO (NUMPART, DESCRIPTION, LOCATION, MAX, ACTUAL, 
MIN, Unidad_de_medida) 
VALUES (@NUMPART, @DESCRIPTION,@LOCATION,@MAX,@ACTUAL,@MIN,@UNIDAD_DE_MEDIDA)"
```

And then:

```
CMD.Parameters.Add("@NUMPART",txtNumParte.Text);
CMD.Parameters.Add("@DESCRIPTION",txtDescripcion.Text);
//...and so on
CMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

*Please* use parameterized SQL (i.e. stored procedures) to prevent SQL injection and the like.

As for your question, you would want to replace the single quote (apostrophe) with two single quotes before you add it as a parameter. This way the first one acts as an escape character which will allow for the apostrophe to be inserted into the database.

Example:
`txtNumParte.Text.Replace("'", "''")`

Comment: Any examples where simply escaping the apostrophes wouldn't stop SQL injection?

Comment: @MichaelZ.thanks for adding the example - makes the answer more complete. As for SQL injection, the way to prevent that is to use parameters, either in a stored procedure or building an insert statement as in the answer provided by Icarus. I focused more on the apostrophe part, as that was the OP's question.

Comment: No problem. I know parameters are best practice, but I'm wondering if escaping apostrophes is enough to prevent SQL injection and I do believe it is. If you can think of an example where it wouldn't work the please comment an example here.